# Conditional object ACL

Tags: parse-platform

New to Parse, coming from Google Firebase, I am not able to completely wrap my head around the security aspect of the platform, let alone write some code. From Firebase, I'm used to writing security rules, by defining conditions that need to be met for certain actions to be allowed (such as: allow write if `owner` field of post is equal to the current users `uid`).

So how would I solve following problem? I have an object `Post` containing properties `title`, `content`, `owner`, `public`.

Allow **reading** under following conditions:

- if `public == true`
- or `currentUser` matches field `owner`

Allow **writing** if `currentUser` matches field `owner`.

Is there a way to implement this? I have found a solution to restrict writing using Cloud Functions, although I am certain there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the writing rule, you can use [Pointer Permission](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#pointer-permissions) in your CLP. But, for the reading rule, you will actually have to write a [beforeFind](http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforefind-triggers) trigger.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Does CLP works on objects that are not on the database yet? I remember that object has to exist first to be checked by CLP. I once tried checking create box on a user pointer but it gave a permission denied error.

Comment: There are two secutiry layers: CLP (Class Level Permissions) and ACL (Access Control List). CLP works in the class level, so any rule there will be applied for the whole class and any new object should pass CLP rules before being saved. ACL works in the object level, so it only applies for existing objects and it is usually set when you are creating a new object. Any operation needs to pass both CLP and ACL to be allowed. Take a look [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#security)

Comment: @DaviMacêdo So I created a class called Test. I added a new field called user and it is a pointer to the User class. I unchecked the write permission for public and gave my user pointer read and write access. When I try to create an object as the user I gave access to create an object, it gives an error:    "error": "Permission denied for action create on class Test."

Comment: Can you please edit your question (or create a new) with the code that you are using to create the object?